# React-router first fetch required data, then show current route's component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

What's the best way of making sure that my react app has all the data needed when I am using react router? Basically I want to fetch some basic data that are used across whole application, the problem is that when I did it "the easy way" some of my data are fetched twice.

When I enter index route (Dashboard) it first mount this component and fire `this.props.fetchAllProjects()`, than it mount Loader component and fire `this.props.fetchUsersInfo()` so it shows just Spinner component and after user info data are fetched id again mount Dashboard and fire `this.props.fetchAllProjects()` is there any good way of doing this?
Here's my current code:

AppRouter.jsx

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route component={Loader}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
        <IndexRoute components={{ rightSidebar: RightSidebar, main: Dashboard }} />
        <Route path="accounts" components={{ rightSidebar: RightSidebar, main: Accounts }} />
    </Route>
</Route>
<Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
```

Loader.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchUsersInfo } from 'actions/index.actions';
import Spinner from 'components/spinner/Spinner.component';
class Loader extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUsersInfo();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.appState.isFetchingUsersInfo ?
                    <div>
                        <Spinner />
                    </div>
                    :
                    <div>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Loader.propTypes = {
    children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    appState: React.PropTypes.shape({
        isFetchingUsersInfo: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    }),
    fetchUsersInfo: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    appState: {
        isFetchingUsersInfo: state.appState.isFetchingUsersInfo,
    },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUsersInfo })(Loader);
```

Dashboard.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchAllProjects } from 'actions/index.actions';

import styles from './Dashboard.container.scss';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchAllProjects();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            Dashboard
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
    appState: React.PropTypes.shape({
        isFetchingProjects: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    }),
    fetchAllProjects: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    appState: {
        isFetchingProjects: state.appState.isFetchingProjects,
    },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchAllProjects })(Dashboard);
```

Comment: `this.props.fetchAllProjects();` and `this.props.fetchUsersInfo();` calls you want to execute once ??

Comment: `this.props.fetchUsersInfo();` is execuded once but the problem is that `this.props.fetchAllProjects();` is called twice and the whole component is mounted twice as well

Comment: y u r calling `this.props.fetchAllProjects();` in Dashbord, do all the api calls that are common to whole application in `MainLayout` component .

Comment: `this.props.fetchAllProjects()` should be called just in Dashboard component, `this.props.fetchUsersInfo();` is used across whole app, I just want to load it and during the loading of those data I want to show loaded and just then show app